# SET initial sum to zero in mysql

Tags: mysql, math, set, operation

I have a query that does what I need, but because a joomla addon for charts doesn't accept the initial SET value to zero, I need a way to transform this query in to a view, or at least to perform the arithmetic function without using SET.

Basically, this query shows a column for each month with the total number of employees, adding those from last month and subtracting the ones who left.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(q1.d,'-',LPAD(q1.m,2,0)) AS Periodo,
q1.c AS `<font color="blue">Assunzioni</font>`,
q1.l AS `<font color="red">Licenziamenti</font>`
FROM
 (SELECT
   YEAR(calendar.datefield) AS d,
   month(calendar.datefield) AS m,
   SUM(statistica_assunti_n.assunzioni) AS c,
   SUM(statistica_licenziati_n.licenziamenti) AS l
FROM  calendar
INNER JOIN statistica_assunti_n
ON calendar.datefield = statistica_assunti_n.data_assunzioni
INNER JOIN statistica_licenziati_n
ON calendar.datefield = statistica_licenziati_n.data_licenziamenti
WHERE YEAR(datefield) ={$REQUEST:chartYearStart|empty:'2011'} 
AND datefield       <= DATE(NOW())
GROUP  BY d, m
ORDER  BY d, m) AS q1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The addon's admin gave me the solution, (SELECT @runtot := 0) AS zero:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(q1.d,'-',LPAD(q1.m,2,0)) AS Periodo,
   (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c - q1.l) AS `N. dipendenti`
FROM
   (SELECT
       YEAR(calendar.datefield) AS d,
       month(calendar.datefield) AS m,
       SUM(statistica_assunti_n.assunzioni) AS c,
       SUM(statistica_licenziati_n.licenziamenti) AS l
    FROM  calendar
    INNER JOIN statistica_assunti_n
    ON calendar.datefield = statistica_assunti_n.data_assunzioni
  INNER JOIN statistica_licenziati_n
    ON calendar.datefield = statistica_licenziati_n.data_licenziamenti
WHERE YEAR(datefield) = {$REQUEST:chartYearStart|empty:'2011'} AND datefield <= DATE(NOW())
    GROUP  BY d, m
    ORDER  BY d, m) AS q1, (SELECT @runtot := 0) AS zero
```